# Javascript code only runs at times

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails web application found [here](http://testbikeberlin.herokuapp.com/products)

Github repo [here](https://github.com/Kotoriii/TestApp1)

It adds data dynamically to different columns. Because I want to have the grid layout (Bootstrap) to be responsive even with a same column height, I am using a Javascript approach, which is between script tags right before the end of the body.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var heights = $(".prodcol").map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get(),

maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
$(".prodcol").height(maxHeight);
});
```

This code runs just fine on a development server in Xubuntu, using Chromium or Firefox. When uploading to Heroku and using Windows and Chrome or Firefox, the same height column script sometimes works or sometimes not (by refreshing the page). When not, the columns will have different heights. I've tried changing the script to onload(), load() and probably other listeners, and it doesn't work at all this way.

I find it odd that it only works at times and that it works perfectly with Chromium. Could anybody point out what it is? Thank you for your help, I've been stuck in this for hours and I'm slowly growing desperate.

Edit: For now I decided to use a fixed height and restrict char limits and img size for the column class, as the issue couldn't be solved so far, so the Heroku link will display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

With turbolinks, I found that using `$(document).ready` can cause issues, instead you could try using:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load',function(){})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip! However, same issue still happening. Sometimes the whole column is wrapped (max height), sometimes it doesn't. I uploaded that attempt to the first link I posted